# Firebase Licence For Open Source Project

Tags: firebase

Is there any free Firebase License available for Open source projects?? I have searched their website but not able to find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase has a generous Free Plan that allows to up to 100 concurrent connections. There are no plans specialized for open-source projects. However, the Free Plan tends to suit most OSS needs.